# Android: Change language of the screen on click of spinner item

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the language of screen, and the language options are set in a spinner. Currently the language is updated when I `Manually reload` the screen. But I want to update the ui on clicking of the language in spinner.

How can I do that??

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually reload'? You run again the application using a view with another language, or what?

Comment: click on a button (ON A) to load one activity (B), and on B i click a button to load A again... but I don't want to go to B, Restarting same intent from the application causes my application to run on out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setOnItemClickListener method of Spinner widget... And set adapter to spinner to view items on spinner...